# Android: Creating a ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm just new in android.. i just wanna ask how to create a actionbar ??.. without using a import com.markupartist.android.widget.Actionbar that comes from a project that I have been downloaded..  Thank you .. I'm using a 2.2 version

Comment: Have you read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html?

Comment: im using a old version of android sdk ... it is for 3.0 above only?

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a ActionBar by default, if your app runs HC+ (and you use the holo theme). However, since the ActionBar got introduced with HC (API Level 11) you have to use [`ActionBarSherlock`](http://actionbarsherlock.com), if you want to use it on pre HC devices.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Android Developers guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html):

> Beginning with Android 3.0 (API level 11), the action bar is included
>   in all activities that use the Theme.Holo theme (or one of its
>   descendants), which is the default theme when either the
>   targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion attribute is set to "11" or greater.

Thus you simply need to set

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />
```

or

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml. You can, of course, set either to higher than 11 as needed, but 11 is the minimum for automatically including the ActionBar.

Comment: i use a old sdk version 2.2

Comment: In that case, use ActionBarSherlock as per Ahmad's answer above.

Comment: ohh I try that one..but when I import the library from the ActionBarSherlock to the Eclipse there's error inside of it but in the tutorial that I watch there is none...

Comment: And what is that error? I'm guessing it is a problem with your environment, as ActionBarSherlock is a very widely used library, and a problem in the source would not go unnoticed.

Comment: The errors are like this:
" AccessibilityNodeInfo cannot be resolved to a type"
"ActionBar cannot be resolved to a type"
" actionBarWidgetTheme cannot be resolved or is not a field"
"ActionMode cannot be resolved to a type " and a lot more...

i think the android 2.2 is the problem? because when i set it in 4.2 there is no error but it cannot run in my program ..

Comment: Just to be sure- You have ActionBarSherlock open in Eclipse as a separate project, and you are linking to it in your application by adding it as a library project, right?

Comment: as the tutorial that i watch only the library can be import to the eclipse ,, yes I'm linking it , to appear the ActionBar??

Comment: And you are seeing these errors in the ActionBarSherlock library project, not your application?

Comment: For both the ActionBarSherlock library and your application, what  version are you compiling against? What are your min and target SDKs?

Comment: For the ActionBarSherlock Library the Min is 7 ,the Target is 8 while  in my application  the min is 8 and the target is 9.. it should be equal???

Comment: First check the build targets by right clicking the project, then going to properties > Android.

Comment: Both of them. Then post back what API they are compiling against.

Comment: Their build targets are the same .. I set it on 2.2 but based on what i said earlier there is error in the Library.. API ? where can i find it??.

Comment: I would recommend posting to the [ActionBarSherlock mailing list](https://groups.google.com/group/actionbarsherlock).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ActionBar in your project, then just download it from this link
[Download Actionbar library project](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar)

- Now import this project into your eclipse.
- After that set it as library in your project.

Its done...